# How to get file path in browser (using protocol or other method to get full path)

Tags: macos, browser, protocols

Using a desktop mac computer, is it possible to enable someone to drag and drop a file into a web page and return the **full path** of the file?

[image]

Having something similar to the S3 dialogue box and then enabling a user to drag a file in there and the full path show up. Would this be possible to do within the browser alone? What about with a protocol that the user has installed on his computer? For example, something like: https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/entries/127152-Launching-External-Applications-using-Custom-Protocols-under-OSX. If so, how would that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be possible to do it through the browser alone.

[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

As for some other workaround, I am not sure.